# Is according access to a private member to a specific object considered bad practice?

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if it was considered a bad practice, or something that breaks the rules of OOP, the fact of according an access to a private member to a specific object.
To be really clear here is a code example.

```
// A special class used to perform some operations on a "Restricted" object
class RestrictedExplorer
{
public:
   Explorer(SpecificData * data) : m_data(data) {}

private:
   SpecificData * m_data;
};

// This class is the only one able to give access to its private member to an explorer
class Restricted
{
public:
   Restricted() { /* ... */ }
   RestrictedExplorer * getExplorer() { return new RestrictedExplorer(m_data); }

private:
   SpecificData * m_data;
   OtherData * m_other;
};
```

We can see that the class itself allow a specific object to use its private data, and it only gives a part of its private member. Plus, it's impossible for another RestrictedExplorer to have access to the private member of a Restricted object by itself.

As long as the RestrictedExplorer respect the encapsulation, is this design something to avoid because it breaks the OOP, or is it possible to use it ?

Thanks by advance

PS : It's for a school project, we are not allowed to use friend

Comment: Do you mean OOP?  POO is something... different.

Comment: It depends.  Sometimes you need this.  Using `new`, however, is a bad idea.  Learn about `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: POO = OOP in French (and probably other languages), prolly just a minor translation quirk.

Comment: Indeed OOP, i'm sorry i'm french and POO is the french acronym

Comment: If you want one class to have access to another class's private data, check out [friendship](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/)

Answer (score 0):

Without a specific context (use-case), there isn't a correct form. The above getter/setting of a private member is fine as long as the class does not make assumptions as to the internals of m_data as you are allowing others to control its contents. If it does then it should not provide a mutable interface to it.

Some (likely most) would consider the above a good practice for any member variable that should be public as you can at lease observe access to the variable through the getter.  If it were a public member variable you would not be able to do so.

Comment: At the beginning, it was for a graph class. We were planing to allow the graph to return a node object, itslef able to return an arc object. But the problem is, that each node should store the arcs leaving it AND the arcs comming to it. There is a duplication of each arc (because it's two differents arc objects stored in the two concerned nodes),and asking the users to add the arc in both nodes by himself is not clean. I started to think about something like an iterator on the graph's nodes, but i wanted to avoid méthod duplications.

Comment: Also, we must use visual studio, and not a version more recent than VS 2012. We are not allowed to use libraries too (for example, vector and string are forbidden), so i guess that i'm forced to use new instead of smart pointers.